# Validar formulario para que no tome espacios en blanco

Tags: javascript, validación

me gustaría poder validar un input para que al apretar la tecla "espacio" esta no surja ningún efecto en el input.

Esto es lo que tengo

```
if ($('#correo').val().trim() == "") {
            mensajeAlert("El campo correo es obligatorio");
            return false;
        }
```

Actualmente, si el campo se encuentra vacío, muestra el mensaje de error.

Comment: <input type="email" value="" placeholder="correo@email.com" required />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
$(function() {
    $('#correo').on('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 32)
            return false;
    });
});
```

Aquí puedes ver el ejemplo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLpY/)

Tomado de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024825/not-allow-a-blank-character-space-in-a-input-form) en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas tardes Arnell, ese código debería de funcionarte sin problemas, lo unico que se me ocurre es que no tengas linkeado bien la librería de jQuery, aún así pruebalo de esta otra manera usando JavaScript nativo (entiendo que el if lo incluyes en una funcion que llamas al hacer click en el submit):

```
if (document.getElementById("correo").value.trim() == "") {
    alert("El campo correo es obligatorio");
    return false;
}
```

También te recomiendo que antes de asegurarte de el funcionamiento utilices un alert que es seguro que no falla y se ve rapido y sencillo.

Comment: Esta solución no responde a la pregunta: no se pasa la validación, pero sí hay un efecto en el input y los espacios se enviarán al servidor. Y usar alerts o no es opinable